# Sharepoint webpart height problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, css, spfx-webparts, responsive

We are developing intranet using SharePoint Framework webparts. I am facing an issue with height of custom webpart (react). One time the webpart has set min-height style, which works perfectly, but on some another PC station in local intranet, SharePoint set fixed height and then the other webparts overflow.

Anybody face same issue?

Fix Height:

[image: Fix]

Min-Height:

[image: MinHeight]

Comment: Can you confirm it's not a caching issue? Try reloading the page without cache by using `STRG` + `F5`

Comment: About cache we tried everything. This does not seem to be cache problem. Also we tried to delete whole webpart from sharepoint, return to previous version but still nothing. I curious, how webpart count the dynamic height of themselve. Sometimes is very accurate, but sometimes is over hundreds pixels or less.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you set the CSS-rule yourself? You may give a try to add `!important` to your css, that pretty much overwrites existing CSS-rules (if you have access to), so: `min-height: 154px !important;`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to handle this div with fixed height, despite it is out of iframe? Can´t access that because have no class or id.

Comment: I've posted a sample code as answer, please let me know if that helps. If you have any element in the DOM-tree that hasn't any class or id, you can always go up the DOM-tree and start from any element that has any class or id.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of investigations, finally solved this problem. This issue is always when you setup webpart as domain isolated. If webpart is not domain isolated, everything is ok.

Hope someone will help this.